# Graph coloring, list index out of range

Tags: python, networkx, gurobi

i'm trying to create a graph with colors associated to the edges using networkx. Each edge should have all the colors but only one will be choosed.

```
Z = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for colored_arc in ((u,v,z) for u,v in G.edges() for z in Z):
    G[colored_arc[0]][colored_arc[1]][colored_arc[2]] = colored_arc
```

where u,v are the nodes and z is the color. This is the result

```
for u,v in G.edges():
    for z in Z:
         print(G[u][v][z])

 (1, 2, 0)
 (1, 2, 1)
 (1, 2, 2)
 (1, 2, 3)
 (1, 2, 4)
 (1, 2, 5)
 (1, 2, 6)
 .....
```

now i'm creating a binary variable (using gurobi), where 1 is the value associated with the right color for each edge, all the other colors have value 0.

```
 mdic = gb.Model()
 for u,v in G.edges():
      for z in Z:
           x = mdic.addVars(obj=[G[u][v][z]], ub = 1.0, vtype=gb.GRB.BINARY, name='x')
```

but this is the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-be25e6af1ffe> in <module>()
  5 for u,v in G.edges():
  6     for z in Z:
----> 7         x = mdic.addVars(obj=[G[u][v][z]], ub = 1.0, vtype=gb.GRB.BINARY, name='x')
  8 
  9 # decision variables s i and S i for i ∈ V to represent the minimum and maximum color in the set of colors

model.pxi in gurobipy.Model.addVars (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:80144)()

model.pxi in gurobipy.__listify.__init__ (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:50924)()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What is G? Could you provide your whole code?

Comment: i missed just the graph creation:


`G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from ([1,2,3,4,5])
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(4,2)
G.add_edge(3,1)
G.add_edge(5,4)
G.add_edge(3,5)

# list of nodes
U = list(G.nodes)

# variable with number of edges
K = G.number_of_edges()
Z = []

# creating a list with colors. We assume that K = {0, 1, . . . , K − 1} and K ≤ |E|
def nrofCol():
    Z.clear()
    z = 0
    while z < K - 1:
        Z.append(z)
        z = z+1
    return Z

Z = nrofCol()
Z`
@JohnnyDrama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mdic.addVar(...)` instead of `mdic.addVars(...)` to create a single decision variable.
Function `addVars` requires a list of indicies according to http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_model_addvars.html, which you don't provide. Therefore you get the `IndexError`.
You can store the variables in a list to get their values after optimizing the model.

```
# n: number of nodes
x = [[[None] * len(Z)] * (n+1)] * (n+1)

for u,v in G.edges():
    for z in Z:
        x[u][v][z] = mdic.addVar(vtype = gb.GRB.BINARY)

mdic.update()

# add constraints using the variables in x...
# add objective function...

mdic.optimize()

# get results using x[u][v][z].getAttr(GRB.Attr.x)
```

### Alternative using addVars

```
indices = []

for u,v in G.edges(): 
    for z in Z:
        indices.append((u,v,z))

x = mdic.addVars(indices, vtype = gb.GRB.BINARY)
```

Comment: Changing to: `for u,v in G.edges(): for z in Z: x = mdic.addVar(obj=G[u][v][z], ub = 1.0, vtype=gb.GRB.BINARY, name='x'+str(u)+str(v)+str(z))` i have the error `TypeError: must be real number, not tuple`  @Cepheus

Comment: You don't need the obj parameter. It's the coefficient in the objective function. You can also set the objective function later. I think you also don't need ub for binary variables. Look at the python example in http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/quickstart_windows.pdf, page 69.

Comment: removing obj, x has just one value

`<gurobi.Var x456>`
@Cepheus

Comment: @Mike Let me know if it solves your problem. If yes, I would appreciate if you could up-vote and accept my answer.

Comment: Could you please take a look to my other question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012650/graph-coloring-gurobi-constraints

@Cepheus

Comment: Could you please take a look to my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263559/graph-coloring-with-intervals-gurobi-constraints
@Cepheus