# Graph coloring Gurobi constraints

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, gurobi

I'm trying to fix some constraints for the Graph coloring problem using networkx and gurobi.  This is all the code that i wrote:

```
import networkx as nx
import gurobi as gb
from itertools import combinations, chain
import pygraphviz as pygv
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import SVG, display
```

Creation of the graph, adding nodes and edges and two lists.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from ([1,2,3,4,5])
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(2,4)
G.add_edge(3,5)
G.add_edge(4,5)
U = list(G.nodes)
K = G.number_of_edges()
Z = []
```

creating a list with colors. We assume that K = {0, 1, . . . , K − 1} and K ≤ |E|

```
def nrofCol():
    Z.clear()
    z = 0
    while z < K - 1:
        Z.append(z)
        z = z+1
    return Z

Z = nrofCol()
```

adding color attribute to each edge

```
for colored_arc in ((u,v,z) for u,v in G.edges() for z in Z):
    G[colored_arc[0]][colored_arc[1]][colored_arc[2]] = colored_arc
```

and added variables to the model using Gurobi:

```
mdic = gb.Model()
indices = []

for u,v in G.edges(): 
    for z in Z:
        indices.append((u,v,z))

# binary variable that assing 1.0 to the color associated to the edge and 0.0 to the others

x = mdic.addVars(indices, vtype = gb.GRB.BINARY)

# decision variable S i for i ∈ V represents the maximum color in the set of colors assigned to edges incident to vertex i

S_i = []
for u in U:
    S_i.append(mdic.addVar(vtype=gb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = G.degree[u] - 1, ub = K - 1, \
                        name = 'max_color'+str(u)))

# decision variable s_i for i ∈ V represents the minimum color in the set of colors assigned to edges incident to vertex i
s_i = []
for u in U:
    s_i.append(mdic.addVar(vtype=gb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0.0, ub = K - G.degree[u], \
                        name='min_color'+str(u)))

mdic.update()
```

And then the constraints:

```
# 1a- Guarantee that adjacent edges take different colors

for u in U:
    for z in Z: 
        mdic.addConstr(x.sum(u,'*',z) <= 1, name='different_color')


mdic.update()


# 1a- Guarantee that adjacent edges take different colors

for u in U:
    for z in Z:
        mdic.addConstr(x.sum('*',u,z) <= 1, name='different_color')


mdic.update()

# 1b- Guarantee that every edge takes exactly one color
for u,v in G.edges():
    mdic.addConstr(x.sum(u,v) == 1, name='one_color')

mdic.update()

# 1c- Enforce Si to be greater than or equal to the max color assigned to the edges incident to vertex i

expr = 0
for u,v in G.edges():
    for z in Z:       
        expr += z * x[u,v,z]
    mdic.addConstr(S_i[u] >= expr, name='max')
    expr = 0

# 1d- Enforce si to be less than or equal to the min color assigned to the edges incident to vertex i

expr = 0
for u,v in G.edges():
    for z in Z:       
        expr += z * x[u,v,z]
mdic.addConstr(s_i[u] <= expr, name='min')
expr = 0

mdic.update()
```

where Z is the set of available colors.

```
# objective function
expr20=0
for u in U:
    expr20+=(S_i[u] - s_i[u] - G.degree[u] + 1)
mdic.setObjective(expr20, gb.GRB.MINIMIZE)

mdic.update()

mdic.optimize()
```

[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUZcm.jpg)

The first one is the objective function, 1a to 1d are the constraints and the others are ub and lb.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code doesn't run as given, due to several missing dependencies.

Comment: Also, you didn't supply any reference to gurobi functionality your program and comments assume: you're restricting your audience to gurobi gurus.  If the problem is in the set-up alone, rather than the optimization step, you've excluded many of us who might solve it.

Comment: A simple explanation of the algorithm would help.  For instance, why are you adding every color to every edge?  How do you determine which color is associated with each edge initially, so you can be "assing 1.0" to it?  Why are you using floats for what appears to be a binary value?  Is this merely an initial condition for what is later merely probability-type weights?

Comment: Did you call S_i after optimizing your model? What is your objective function? What are the lower and upper bounds of S_i?

Comment: yes, S_i  is called after optimizing the model. You can see the lb and up in the declaration of S_i. Here the objective function that return index out of range error.

`expr=0
for u in U:
    expr+=(S_i[u] - s_i[u] - G.degree[u] + 1)
mdic.setObjective(expr, gb.GRB.MINIMIZE)`

Comment: You should put the objective function into the question. What is `s_i[u]`? Is it a typo and you mean `S_i[u]`? If so, then the problem is that `S_i[u] - S_i[u] == 0`, so you don't optimize any of your decision variables. And I don't understand how you could optimize the model if this line already throws an error.

Comment: S_i and s_i are the maximum and minimum colors in the set of colors assigned to edges incident to vertex i, respectively. 
I could optimize the model just removing the line of the objective function. @Cepheus

Comment: If the model is optimized without an objective function, you will get meaningless default values for the decision variables. You should find out, what causes the error. I don't see it based on the information your provided. Maybe you can provide the full error message.

Comment: I added all the code and the specific error returned by the objective function. @Cepheus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use an undirected graph, I found several problems:

Constraint (1a) in your screenshot ensures that adjacent edges have different colors. However, with your implementation of this constraint it could happen that an incoming and an outgoing edge have the same color. E.g., edge {1,3} and {3,5} could have the same color. That's because you handle incoming and outgoing edges separately. As a solution, your could combine your loops into one:

```
for u in U:
    for z in Z: 
        mdic.addConstr(x.sum(u,'*',z) + x.sum('*',u,z) <= 1, name='different_color')
```

Constraint (1c) also considers only outgoing edges in your implementation. E.g., `S_i[5]` would not be assigned because it has only incoming edges. This should work:

```
expr = 0
for u,v in G.edges():
    for z in Z:       
        expr += z * x[u,v,z]
    mdic.addConstr(S_i[u] >= expr, name='max')
    mdic.addConstr(S_i[v] >= expr, name='max')
    expr = 0
```

The same goes for constraint (1d). Morover the `addConstr` line is outside of the loop, but this could just be a formatting error:

```
expr = 0
for u,v in G.edges():
    for z in Z:       
        expr += z * x[u,v,z]
    mdic.addConstr(s_i[u] <= expr, name='min')
    mdic.addConstr(s_i[v] <= expr, name='min')
    expr = 0
```

Comment: Using the second option it is working, but not properly. There are 2 outgoing edges from a node with the same color and max and min colors are wrong. I uploaded the constraints image in the question, could you check if i made some mistakes? @Cepheus

Comment: I honestly don't know how two outgoing edges can have the same color because that's what your first constraint prevents. But I found other issues. @Mike

Comment: Could you please take a look to my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263559/graph-coloring-with-intervals-gurobi-constraints
@Cepheus