# Graph coloring with intervals Gurobi constraints

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, gurobi

I'm trying to fix some constraints for the Graph coloring problem using networkx and gurobi. For each i ∈ V, we define the following set of intervals. Each interval [l,u] ∈ Ii represents a possible pair of minimum color l and maximum color u for the set of edges incident to vertex i. Also, for each k∈K , we represent the set of intervals for vertex i ∈ V which include color k by :

[Intervals variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XctNo.jpg)

This is all the code that i wrote:

```
import networkx as nx
import gurobi as gb
from itertools import combinations, chain
import pygraphviz as pygv
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import SVG, display
```

Creation of the graph, adding nodes and edges and two lists.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from ([0,1,2,3,4])
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(0,2)
G.add_edge(0,3)
G.add_edge(0,4)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(2,4)
G.add_edge(3,4)
U = list(G.nodes)
K = G.number_of_edges()
Z = []
```

creating a list with colors. We assume that K = {0, 1, . . . , K − 1} and K ≤ |E|

```
def nrofCol():
    Z.clear()
    z = 0
    while z < K - 1:
        Z.append(z)
        z = z+1
    return Z

Z = nrofCol()
Z
```

here i'm defining the value of the interval (l,u), creating two list with all the colors.

```
u = []
l = []

for z in Z:
    u.append(Z[z])
    l.append(Z[z])
```

I will be a list of tuple

```
I = []
for z in Z:
    for u in range (z, len(Z)):
        I.append(tuple((z, u)))
```

adding color attribute to each edge

```
for colored_arc in ((u,v,z) for u,v in G.edges() for z in Z):
    G[colored_arc[0]][colored_arc[1]][colored_arc[2]] = colored_arc
```

and added variables to the model using Gurobi:

[Variable y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK5Ci.jpg)

```
indices = []

for u,v in G.edges(): 
    for z in Z:
        indices.append((u,v,z))

x = mdic.addVars(indices, vtype = gb.GRB.BINARY)

indices2 = []

for u in G.nodes(): 
    for i in range(0,len(I)): 
        indices2.append(tuple((u,I[i])))

for u in U:
    y = mdic.addVars(indices2, vtype = gb.GRB.BINARY)

mdic.update()
```

Constraints are:
[Contraints and objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dygzs.jpg)

Constraints 2a- Ensure that each edge takes exactly one color

```
for u,v in G.edges():

        mdic.addConstr(x.sum(u,v) == 1, name='one_color')

mdic.update()
```

2b- Choose exactly one interval (from the set of eligible intervals) for each vertex.

```
for u in U:       
    mdic.addConstr(y.sum(u) == 1, name='used')

mdic.update()
```

2c- Guarantee that not only adjacent edges take different colors, but also edges incident to a vertex take colors from the set of colors included in the interval chosen for that vertex

```
for u in U:
    for z in Z: 
        mdic.addConstr((x.sum(u,'*',z) + x.sum('*',u,z)) <= y.sum(u,I), name='different_colors')

mdic.update()
```

objective function

```
expr=0
for u in U:
    for i in range(0,len(I)):
        a = [i[1] for i in I][i]
        b = [i[0] for i in I][i]
        expr += (a - b - G.degree[u] + 1) * y[u,I[i]]
mdic.setObjective(expr, gb.GRB.MINIMIZE)

mdic.update()
mdic.optimize()
```

Using this code, the model is unfeasible. I know that variable x and constraints 2a are defined in the right way. I'm not sure about variable y, other constraints and the objective function. How can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval list `I[i]` should be defined for each node separately:

```
I = []
for i in G.nodes():
    Ii = []
    for z in Z:
        for u in range (z, len(Z)):
            if u - z >= G.degree(i) - 1:
                Ii.append(tuple((z, u)))
    I.apppend(Ii)
```

The usage of `I` must then be changed to something like this:

```
indices2 = []

for i in G.nodes(): 
    for interval in I[i]: 
        indices2.append(tuple((i,interval)))
```

Variables `y` should now only be created once:

```
y = mdic.addVars(indices2, vtype = gb.GRB.BINARY)
```

Constraint 2c must also be changed because in your screenshot the right sum iterates only over a subset of `I`:

```
for u in U:
    for z in Z:

        y_sum = 0
        for z1,z2 in I[u]:
            if z1 <= z and z <= z2:
                y_sum += y[u,(z1,z2)]

        mdic.addConstr((x.sum(u,'*',z) + x.sum('*',u,z)) <= y_sum, name='different_colors')
```

Comment: Model is still unfeasible. Probably there is an error with Constraints 2c, maybe y(u,I) is not working. Same for the objective function. How could i fix it? @Cepheus

Comment: @Mike Constraint 2c must also be changed. But I didn't check the objective function because it shouldn't affect feasibility.